# The difference between "en quoi" and "pourquoi"

Tags: sens, interrogative

> **En quoi** ma relation avec elle t'intéresse-t-elle ?
>
> **Pourquoi** ma relation avec elle t'intéresse-t-elle ?

How does using "en quoi" here differ in meaning from a straightforward question with "pourquoi"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***En quoi*** asks for a specific detail (**what/how**?) while ***pourquoi*** asks for a global motivation/explanation (**why**?).

- ***En quoi*** : What aspect of my relationship with her interests you?
- ***Pourquoi*** : Why does my relationship with her interest you?

Assuming these questions are asked in a jealousy context, I would also say the first question sounds more aggressive (i.e. it's none of your business) while the second one is more neutral (there is nothing to worry about).

Here are other contexts showing the difference between these expressions:

- ***En quoi*** es-tu venu ici ? How did you get here? (by car/plane/bus/...)
- ***Pourquoi*** es-tu venu ici ? Why did you get here? (because I wanted/needed to)
- ***En quoi*** puis-je vous être utile ? How can I help you?
- ***Pourquoi*** puis-je vous être utile ? (not idiomatic) Why can I help you?
- ***En quoi*** vas-tu te déguiser ? What are you going to dress-up as?
- ***Pourquoi*** vas-tu te déguiser ? Why will you disguise yourself?

Comment: Hmmm, la traduction proposée de "en quoi" me fait plutot penser à "Qu'est-ce qui, dans ma relation avec elle t'interesse ?". y aurait-il une nuance ?

Comment: @Random        Do you mean something like: "In what part/aspect of my relationship with her are you interested?" Merci.

Comment: @Random Oui, « en quoi » est en effet plus proche de « qu'est-ce qui, dans » que de « pourquoi ».

Comment: @LUNA this would fit better with "En quoi" yeah